# VK API : Как экспортировать полученный JSON в CSV или Как отсортировать txt - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
import pickle
import json

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi('login', 'Pass') # логин и пароль
vk_session.auth()
vk = vk_session.get_api()


def main():

    y = vk.groups.getMembers(group_id='your_group_id', fields='contacts') # Id группы и номера телефонов пользователей этой группы

    data = y
    json_str = json.dumps(data)
    resp = json.loads(json_str)
    print(resp)
    print(resp['items'])
    data_items = str(resp['items'])

    with open("файл.txt", "w") as file:
    print(data_items, file=file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Таким образом я получаю JSON вида :

```
{'items': [{'first_name': 'Оля', 'id': 111111, 'last_name': 'Сущенко'}, {'first_name': 'Георгий', 'id': 222222, 'last_name': 'Голосов'}, {'first_name': 'Максим', 'id': 333333, 'home_phone':+79909999999 '', 'last_name': 'Тупиченков'}
```

который в свою очередь является dict - тоесть словарь , я правильно понимаю ? Подскажите пожалуйста.

И как мне этот JSON экспортировать в csv ? все мои потуги заканчивались только тем , что в одну строку у меня помещатся coutn , а на второй весь 'ответ' JSON (в одну строчку) с ключами словаря и ССЫЛКАМИ НА ДАННЫЕ (как вытянуть эти данные)?. Здесь еще сложность в том, что полученные данные не однообразны , у кого-то указаны контактные данные а у кого-то нет, соостветсвенно и поля home_number/mobile_number могут отсутствовать и я уже предвкушаю во что это выльется при экспорте, как минимум будут проблемы при создании столбцов в таблице , подскажите как правильно решить эту проблему ?

В отчаянии я решил выгрузить всё полученные данные в txt файл, на выходе я получил txt файл типа:

```
{'first_name': 'Оля', 'id': 111111, 'last_name': 'Сущенко'}, {'first_name': 'Георгий', 'id': 222222, 'last_name': 'Голосов'}, {'first_name': 'Максим', 'id': 333333, 'home_phone':+79909999999 '', 'last_name': 'Тупиченков'}
```

может его можно как-то отсортить/отсплитить скриптом, чтобы получить желаемый csv ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы сохранить подобный JSON в CSV его надо превратить в плоскую (без вложений) структуру.

Модуль Pandas позволяет сделать это одной командой.

имея следующий *словарь*:

```
In [80]: d
Out[80]:
{'items': [{'first_name': 'Оля', 'id': 111111, 'last_name': 'Сущенко'},
  {'first_name': 'Георгий', 'id': 222222, 'last_name': 'Голосов'},
  {'first_name': 'Максим',
   'id': 333333,
   'home_phone': '+79909999999',
   'last_name': 'Тупиченков'}]}
```

можно легко превратить его в плоский DataFrame и сохранить его как CSV:

```
In [81]: import pandas as pd

In [82]: df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(d['items'])

In [83]: df
Out[83]:
  first_name    home_phone      id   last_name
0        Оля           NaN  111111     Сущенко
1    Георгий           NaN  222222     Голосов
2     Максим  +79909999999  333333  Тупиченков

In [84]: df.to_csv(r'c:/temp/out.csv', index=False)
```

можно сделать это одной командой:

```
pd.io.json.json_normalize(d['items']).to_csv(r'c:/temp/out.csv', index=False)
```

---

результат (`C:\Temp\out.csv`):

```
first_name,home_phone,id,last_name
Оля,,111111,Сущенко
Георгий,,222222,Голосов
Максим,+79909999999,333333,Тупиченков
```

Comment: Pandas просто шикарный :)

Comment: @gil9red, абсолютно согласен! ;)